# Ruby OAuth with Salesforce not getting refresh_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, salesforce

I can't seem to get a refresh_token whenever I'm authorized, I've tried setting headers, kind of like how it would be done with google oauth, but not luck. Here's my process:

Using `oauth2` gem

**Instantiate client**

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(
  salesforce_app_key,
  salesforce_secret_key,
  site: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/',
  authorize_url: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize',
  token_url: 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
  raise_errors: false
)
```

**Authorize connection**

```
auth = client.auth_code.authorize_url(
  redirect_uri: 'https://my_app_callback.com/oauth/authorize'
)
```

**Fetch token**

```
token = client.auth_code.get_token(
  code,
  redirect_uri: 'https://my_app_callback.com/oauth/authorize'
)
```

From this point, I have the connection set, but when I do `token.refresh_token` I get a nil value.

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(oauth, token)
```

The session was reestablished successfully. It's in the docs, but not written in a way I could uderstand it's used to reauthenticate.